# Best way to count words in a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there anything better than `string.scan(/(\w|-)+/).size` (the `-` is so, e.g., "one-way street" counts as 2 words instead of 3)?

Comment: Define what you mean by "word"? Imagine the following string: "I am ... string." How many words would you expect to be counted?

Comment: very nice question dear

Answer (score 60):

```
string.split.size
```

---

Edited to explain multiple spaces

From the [Ruby String Documentation page](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html)

> split(pattern=$;, [limit]) → anArray
>
> Divides str into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array
>   of these substrings.
>
> If pattern is a String, then its contents are used as the delimiter
>   when splitting str. **If pattern is a single space, str is split on
>   whitespace, with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace
>   characters ignored.**
>
> If pattern is a Regexp, str is divided where the pattern matches.
>   Whenever the pattern matches a zero-length string, str is split into
>   individual characters. If pattern contains groups, the respective
>   matches will be returned in the array as well.
>
> **If pattern is omitted, the value of $; is used. If $; is nil (which is
>   the default), str is split on whitespace as if ' ' were specified.**
>
> If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are
>   suppressed. If limit is a positive number, at most that number of
>   fields will be returned (if limit is 1, the entire string is returned
>   as the only entry in an array). If negative, there is no limit to the
>   number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not
>   suppressed.

```
" now's  the time".split        #=> ["now's", "the", "time"]
```

While that is the current version of ruby as of this edit, I learned on 1.7 (IIRC), where that also worked. I just tested it on 1.8.3.

Comment: This soulution will count spaces as words(empty) too, consider that.

Comment: @DavidMauricio No it won't. `split` without an argument defaults to split on whitespace. (Well, it will split on `$;`, but if that's `nil` too, then it will split on whitespace.) Ruby docs describe this behavior as "with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace characters ignored."

Comment: Wouldn't this unnecessarily create the array of words just to return its size? What if there are 10,000 words in a text? This would waste space and be slower because of this.

Comment: @Ernesto Yes, and... in practice, you can count literally millions of words a second this way and the array is garbage collected. Premature optimization and whatnot.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but this might be useful to someone else looking for something more sophisticated than `string.split`. I wrote the [`words_counted`](https://github.com/abitdodgy/words_counted) gem to solve this particular problem, since defining words is pretty tricky.

The gem lets you define your own custom criteria, or use the out of the box regexp, which is pretty handy for most use cases. You can pre-filter words with a variety of options, including a string, lambda, array, or another regexp.

```
counter = WordsCounted::Counter.new("Hello, Renée! 123")
counter.word_count #=> 2
counter.words #=> ["Hello", "Renée"]

# filter the word "hello"
counter = WordsCounted::Counter.new("Hello, Renée!", reject: "Hello")
counter.word_count #=> 1
counter.words #=> ["Renée"]

# Count numbers only
counter = WordsCounted::Counter.new("Hello, Renée! 123", rexexp: /[0-9]/)
counter.word_count #=> 1
counter.words #=> ["123"]
```

The gem provides a [bunch more useful methods](https://github.com/abitdodgy/words_counted).

Answer (score 2):

If the 'word' in this case can be described as an alphanumeric sequence which can include '-' then the following solution may be appropriate (assuming that everything that doesn't match the 'word' pattern is a separator):

```
>> 'one-way street'.split(/[^-a-zA-Z]/).size
=> 2
>> 'one-way street'.split(/[^-a-zA-Z]/).each { |m| puts m }
one-way
street
=> ["one-way", "street"]
```

However, there are some other symbols that can be included in the regex - for example, ' to support the words like "it's".

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simplistic but does the job if you are typing words with spaces in between. It ends up counting numbers as well but I'm sure you could edit the code to not count numbers.

```
puts "enter a sentence to find its word length: "
word = gets
word = word.chomp
splits = word.split(" ")
target = splits.length.to_s


puts "your sentence is " + target + " words long"
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do is to use *split* method.
*split* divides a string into sub-strings based on a delimiter, returning an array of the sub-strings.
*split* takes two parameters, namely; **pattern** and **limit**.
**pattern** is the delimiter over which the string is to be split into an array.
**limit** specifies the number of elements in the resulting array.
For more details, refer to Ruby Documentation: [Ruby String documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split)

```
str = "This is a string"
str.split(' ').size
#output: 4
```

The above code splits the string wherever it finds a *space* and hence it give the number of words in the string which is indirectly **the size of the array.**

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is wrong, consider the following:

```
"one-way  street"
```

You will get

```
["one-way","", "street"]
```

Use

```
'one-way street'.gsub(/[^-a-zA-Z]/, ' ').split.size
```

Comment: [between one-way and street, there are 2 spaces]

Comment: Nope. Ruby will split on whitespace (contiguous and leading/trailing whitespace is ignored. e.g. `\s+`) if no argument is supplied and `$;` is `nil`. Please learn ruby.

Answer (score 0):

This splits words only on ASCII whitespace chars:

```
p "  some word\nother\tword|word".strip.split(/\s+/).size #=> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

For example count words of "War and peace" in file:

```
acc = 0
File.readlines('war_and_peace.txt').each { |line| acc += line.split.size }

acc
 => 238610
```